# How can I get the caller reference inside another object's called function?

Tags: javascript

Following is the code I am trying :

```
var varincaller;
function mainfunction(arg)
{
 varincaller = arg;
}

function mainfunction2()
{
var obj2 = new anotherclass;

obj2.anotherfunction = function()
{
   //How can I get varincaller, here ?
}
}
```

Can anybody please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, since `varincaller` is defined outside or in the same scope in which `.anotherfunction` is defined, we can access it directly:

```
obj2.anotherfunction = function() {
   varincaller; // this works
};
```

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the the code example. I was trying to use : var that = this and then use the 'that' inside the anotherfunction - in that case I get varincaller to be undefined.

Comment: Because you have not set `varincaller` to be an object property. Inside the constructor of `anotherclass` put in `this.varincaller = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement creates a global variable `varincaller`. So, it's accessible from any function.

```
var varincaller;
```

This statement isn't syntactically sound:

```
var obj2 = new anotherclass;
```

Should be:

```
var obj2 = new anotherClass();
```

To access `varincaller` inside the function in question it is a simple call to it:

```
obj2.anotherfunction = function()
{
   alert(varincaller);
}
obj2.anotherfunction();
```